# Why does this call to `getNoise` use the base class implementation and not the subclass implementation?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

## The problem

My understanding was that we could achieve polymorphim by making `getNoise` virtual in the base, and then overriding it in any subclasses. Then via a vector of pointers, we store the address of the base classes which are used to call methods on such as `getNosie` below.

Could anybody tell me why my code doesn't do this?

## The code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;


class Animals {
private:
    std::string noise = "None";

public:
    Animals() = default;

    virtual ~Animals() = default;

    virtual std::string getNoise() {
        return noise;
    }

};

class Duck : public Animals {
private:
    std::string noise = "Quack!";
public:
    using Animals::Animals;

    std::string getNoise() override {
        return noise;
    }
};

class Dog : public Animals {
private:
    std::string noise = "Bark!";
public:
    using Animals::Animals;

    std::string getNoise() override {
        return noise;
    }
};


class AnimalsContainer {
public:
    std::vector<Animals *> animals;
    Animals *front;

    AnimalsContainer() {
        Duck duck;
        Dog dog;
        animals.push_back(&duck);
        animals.push_back(&dog);
        front = animals[0];
    }

    ~AnimalsContainer() = default;
};


int main() {
    AnimalsContainer animals;
    cout << animals.front->getNoise() << endl;
```

## Expected output

I'm expecting

```
Quack!
```

But I'm getting

```
None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont't you use pointers:

```
Duck* duck = new Duck();
Dog* dog = new Dog();
animals.push_back(duck);
animals.push_back(dog);
```

Instead of

```
Duck duck;
Dog dog;
animals.push_back(&duck);
animals.push_back(&dog);
```

You can then destroy them on the destructor:

```
~AnimalsContainer() {
    for (Animals* a : animals) {
        delete a;
    }
}
```

If you really need noise string "none" in the base class.

Of course the raw pointers are for simplicity, you should maybe use smart pointers.

Answer (score 2):

"std::string noise" should only be declared in the base class, not in the subclasses. Set the noise value in the constructors of the subclasses instead.